# what is $ K_{n}^{k} $ graph?

Tags: graph-theory

We all familiar with **complete bipartite graphs** and **stars** which respectively denote as follow:

**$ K_{m,n} $**  and  **$ S_n $**

But what is the meaning of **$ K_{n}^{k} $** in Graph theory???

here is a  reference to show the application of that notation better:

> [image]

http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Oktatas/Algoritmusok-hatekonysaga/Berge-hypergraphs.pdf

It might seem simple but I hadn't find any useful definition of that already.

Comment: @bof Your guess seems rational thank you so much
So the  $ K_{n}^{r} $ star will be a star hypergraph which all hyperedges  have same size k.

Answer (score 2):

I found the definition of $K^r_n$ on page 5 of the document you linked to,
[*Hypergraphs: Combinatorics of Finite Sets*](http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Oktatas/Algoritmusok-hatekonysaga/Berge-hypergraphs.pdf) by [Claude Berge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Berge):

> Let $r,n$ be integers, $1\le r\le n.$ We define the *$r$-uniform complete hypergraph of order $n$* (or the *$r$-complete hypergraph*) to be a hypergraph denoted $K^r_n$ consisting of all the $r$-subsets of a set $X$ of cardinality $n.$